# How to unpack a struct in another struct in rust?

Tags: rust

Can you do something like this?

```
struct Person {
hp: i32
}

struct EvolvedPerson {
hp: i32,
evolved_stat: i32,
}

let p1 = Person { hp: 10 }
let p2 = EvolvedPerson { ..p1, extra_stat: 20 }
```

Where the p2 now has the hp of p1.

Answer (score 3):

As a possible solution you can deconstruct `p1` and then provide variables to `p2` by shorter syntax:

```rust
struct Person {
    hp: i32
}

struct EvolvedPerson {
    hp: i32,
    evolved_stat: i32,
}

let p1 = Person { hp: 10 };

let p2 = {
    let Person { hp } = p1;
    EvolvedPerson { hp, extra_stat: 20 }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way would be to include the `Person` struct instead:

```rust
struct Person {
    hp: i32,
}

struct EvolvedPerson {
    person: Person,
    evolved_stat: i32,
}

let p1 = Person { hp: 10 }
let p2 = EvolvedPerson { person: p1, extra_stat: 20 }
```

That way it is also trivial to implement `AsRef<Person>` for `EvolvedPerson` and thus you can use `Person` methods with `EvolvedPerson` too.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you do something like this?

No. You can only unpack structs of the same type.